# How to solve this equation manually: $(x^2+100)^2=(x^3-100)^3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Well, I was given a problem,
find $x$, if:

$$(x^2+100)^2=(x^3-100)^3$$

I tried everything that I could, I even opened up the brackets which gave an ugly degree 9 equation, I also tried to plot the curves $y=\left(x^2+100\right)^2$ and $y=\left(x^3-100\right)^3$ and locate their point of intersection but it couldn't be done manually.

So, in the end I was forced to use hit and trial after doing which I got the answer, is their any way to solve this algebraically??

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a quite dirty trick you can use here. Define
$$
f(x,t)=(x^2+t)^2-(x^3-t)^3\ .
$$
Then solve $f(x,t)=0$ for $t$ (not for $x$). There is a simple solution of the cubic equation in $t$
$$
t=x^2(x-1)\ .
$$
Then set $t=100$ and solve the cubic equation for $x$, yielding $x=5$ as the only real root.

Comment: Nice one, although the trick that you used is pretty difficult to come by in the middle of an exam!

Comment: But $t=x^2(x-1)$ is not the only solution. The other solutions are $t=\frac{2x^3+x^2\pm\sqrt{-3x^4 -8x^3-6x^2+1}-1}{2}$, which are real if and only if  $x\in\left[-1,\frac{1}{3}\right]$ (see [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28t%5E2%2Bx%29%5E2-%28t%5E3-x%29%5E3)).

Answer (score 20):

It's obvious that $x^3>100$ so $x>0$ .

Consider the $6$-th root of the equation to get :

$$\sqrt[3]{x^2+100}=\sqrt{x^3-100}$$

Now consider the function :$$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^2+100}$$

This function is bijective from $(0,\infty$) to $(\sqrt[3]{100},\infty)$ .

Its inverse is :$$f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x^3-100}$$

This means that the equation is now :

$$f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$$

$$f(f(x))=x$$

But $f$ is an increasing function so let's take two cases :

- If $f(x)>x$ then :

$$x=f(f(x))>f(x)>x$$ a contradiction .

- If $f(x)<x$ then :
  $$x=f(f(x))<f(x)<x$$ a contradiction .

This means that $f(x)=x$ so : $$x^3=100+x^2$$ which can be solved easily .

Comment: The best solution so far.

Comment: @whatever Thanks . I actually know this trick from some time so when I saw this problem it immediately popped to me that it might work , and it did .

Comment: this questions seems looks like $x = \sqrt{5-\sqrt{5-x}}$

Answer (score 7):

For a particular solution, you can take
$$x=5.$$
How did I find it? I restrict to the case of integers. We are looking for numbers such that $n^2=m^3$. Then, we expect to have $n=k^3$ and $m=k^2$ for some integer $k$. Now, we look for
$$k^3=x^2+100,\quad k^2=x^3-100.$$
Those two equations would be satisfied if $x=k$, and
$$k^3=k^2+100.$$
Now this equation is much simpler. I thought of what integer $k$ is such that $k^3$ is a bit above $100$ and $5^3=125$ was an obvious candidate.

Comment: Sketching a graph of each of the curves gives you that they'll only have one intersection.

Comment: @πr8 well I tried it but i couldn't do it manually

Comment: Couldn't draw it manually? The LHS is going to basically look like a parabola (from a distance) and the RHS like a $y=x^3$ type of curve, and looking at the powers of $x$ in each ought to hint that the RHS will be increasing faster eventually. Verify that this is the case for $x\geq5$ and you have the uniqueness.

Comment: In an examination I have 1 hr for my mathematics section, and I have 30 problems, each unique and difficult(for me), so when I tried to graph it, I got that the curves intersect at only 1 point, but I couldn't get that point. (Considering I gave this problem 3-4 minutes).