# On the equation $\left( x^2+100 \right)^2 = \left( x^3 -100 \right)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve the equation
>
> $$\left( x^2+100 \right)^2 = \left( x^3 -100 \right)^3$$

I have no idea what to do. The equation is part of an exercise that goes as follows:

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that

$$f(f(x)) = x \quad \forall \; x \in \mathbb{R}$$

1. Prove that $f$ is $1-1$ or a bijection. ( done )
2. If $f$ is strictly increasing , then prove that $f(x)=x$. ( done )
3. Solve the equation $\left( x^2+100 \right)^2 = \left( x^3 -100 \right)^3$ using the above.

No idea how to combine the above to solve the equation. I'm interested in solutions that use high school methods preferably no derivatives; just pure functions (e.g composition or simple algebraic manipulations )

Wolfram Alpha gives $x=5$ as a solution.

Comment: does this help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607042/how-to-solve-this-equation-manually-x21002-x3-1003

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve this equation manually: $(x^2+100)^2=(x^3-100)^3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607042/how-to-solve-this-equation-manually-x21002-x3-1003)

Comment: See in particular [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1607072/631494) solution from the linked duplicate.